# Import Python codes inside HTML file

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-3.x

As mentioned [here](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html), I can import Python codes inside .html files using `<%` and `%>` tags.  Just to try it, I wrote the below code in notepad and save it as a file named test.html :

```
<html>
<title>
</title>
<body>
<%print ("Hello")%>
</body>
```

Once I do a double click on the test.html, Chrome opens with the below line on the top  :

```
<%print ("Heloo")%>
```

What I must I do to have 'Hello' in output?

Note: **"print"** is an example, What kind of ways is there to import and run python codes in html files?

Comment: you are using the pythonic web framework?

Comment: @Vizjerei No, What is this? I use Chrome, Firefox , ... Should I add something to this browsers? Or I must use a specific kind of browsers? What is pythonic web framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page is related to Karrigell a Python web framework, you can only have Python and HTML files (Web pages) if you use a Python web framework like [web.py](http://webpy.org/), [Pylons](http://www.pylonsproject.org/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com), and [others](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).

Browsers can only execute JavaScript code, other programming languages have to use special components to be executed by browsers.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to execute python codes that added to a html codes in Google chrome, I must add some components? If I want to build a web page using python codes inside, How I can be sure the peoples who open my webpage see the outputs that I want? (I mean maybe they haven't a pythonic web framework! so I must not use python codes in my  pages?)

Comment: That's why you have to use a web framework, where your pages will be handled by Python code on the backend, but clients will only be served HTML web pages. I suggest you read about web development using Python [read here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/how-do-i-learn-python-from-zero-to-web-development)

Comment: So the server that we upload our pages there, must have a python web framework? web frameworks translate our pages from python to html,once a request from a client received?

Comment: Yes exactly, like I told you [read here about learning Python and python web programming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/how-do-i-learn-python-from-zero-to-web-development).